# How to Update iOS SDK Version in Expo

Tags: ios, sdk, expo

SDK Version Issue - This app was built with the iOS 12.0 SDK. Starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

Because I'm using Expo, how to Update iOS SDK Version in Expo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different scenarios:

**Building on Expo Server**

A quick test:

- built with `expo-cli build:ios`
- version is built on expo.io
- downloaded .ipa
- checked entry DTXcodeBuild in info.plist

This gives the value 10A255, which actually indeed means Xcode 10.0 released on 17 Sep 2018.

As mentioned by Jeaf Gilbert in the comments, Expo is aware of this:

> thanks for reporting! We're aware of this warning and we promise the issue will be resolved before March 2019

see here: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/264

**Ejected to ExpoKit**

If ejected to ExpoKit then Expo is using the SDK of the installed Xcode version, because the building is managed locally.

In this case just install the newest Xcode version. This also includes the newest SDK.

Comment: My Xcode is up to date (currently 10.1). What should I to make Expo using the latest iOS SDK?

Comment: I wrongly assumed you have ejected and are building with Xcode directly: so instead you are building with `expo-cli build:ios` with the newest Expo version? Should already use the newest Xcode, but let me check.

Comment: My Expo version is 31.0.2

Comment: Yes I’m building with `exp build:ios`

Comment: Ah, nice.
Just updated my answer with my test result, but you found a better source, so I will update it once again and add the link there

Answer (score 0):

Bumping your expo SDK version up should do the trick